# Do I use subdomain or domain in SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, subdomain

I have a domain called @desk.com . My imap points to mail.desk.com . As I wont afford subdomain certification, should I buy desk.com or mail.desk.com ?

Comment: Depends which service you want secured.

Comment: Or autodiscover.desk.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is by a wild card cert. These typically cost more, but are much more flexible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Answer (score 1):

You buy the certificate for the *hostname* of the service to which the SSL client will connect.